# calling web service very slow over https

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I have a web site from iis. When I call web service from the site it takes < 1 sec

but if i install certificate from global sign and run my site over https
the same web service method takes 40 second.

PS: The problem is not calling the service, the problem is returning data to back. I add some counter point to find out the bottleneck point. 
Between call, reach and calculate the response are not important time, but the returning data to page is about 40 sec.

Answer (score 0):

Ciphers differ in performance. Try using AES with 128-bit keys and also check if your web server supports AES-NI